# Joda DateTime Overlap and Filtering

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have two Intervals say,

```
// for simplicity, I present here only the hours
val interval1 = (08, 20)
val interval2 = (00, 10)
```

Now, when I do a overlap between the two intervals, I get

```
val overlap = interval.overlap(interval2) // gives me (08, 10)
```

Is there a method in joda-time that I can use to get the non overlapping time periods? I need to get (10, 20)

I tried using the gap method:

```
scala> val a = new Interval(DateTime.parse("2000-10-12T00:00:00"), DateTime.parse("2000-10-12T20:00:00"))

scala> val b = new Interval(DateTime.parse("2000-09-12T00:00:00"), DateTime.parse("2000-10-12T12:00:00"))

a.gap(b) // returns null
b.gap(a) // returns null
```

Comment: What about the [gap()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#gap(org.joda.time.ReadableInterval))-method?

Comment: Nope that does not work either!

Comment: Your example does not show a gap between intervals a and b hence the null-result. It is documented, see the link. Instead your intervals overlap on the date 2000-10-12 between midnight and noon.

Comment: That is why I said that gap does not fit what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is nothing in the library that offers this. So I came up with my own implementation which is like this:

```
  private def splitIntervals(interval1: Interval, interval2: Interval) = {
    Option(interval1.overlap(interval2)) match {
      case Some(overlap) => {
        if (overlap.equals(interval1)) Seq(interval1)
        else if (overlap.equals(interval2))
          Seq(overlap) :+
            new Interval(interval1.getStart, overlap.getStart) :+
            new Interval(overlap.getEnd, interval1.getEnd)
        else if (overlap.getStart.equals(interval1.getStart))
          Seq(overlap) :+
            new Interval(overlap.getEnd, interval1.getEnd)  
        else Seq(overlap) :+
          new Interval(interval1.getStart, overlap.getEnd)
      }
      case _ => Seq(interval1)
    }
  }
```

It covers all the possible edge cases!

Comment: +1 for your efforts. I have misunderstood your requirements (it seems you rather looked for a partial xor-relationship between intervals a and b). The Joda-solution looks somehow complex however because there is no native support for such a feature like `a.xor(b)` (partial because you leave out (0,8)).

Comment: I hate those if else-if ladder only if that could be made better!

Comment: That's one extra reason why I have implemented more interval features beyond what Joda-Time offers. See [the range-package in Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#xor-net.time4j.range.IntervalCollection-) But I don't know if my library can be used in Scala, too (no experiences).